# jQuery tablesorter with row numbers

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am using the [jQuery Tablesorter 2.0 plugin](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) to provide some basic table sorting functionality.

On my table, I would like to have a column for row number.  The trouble is, the Tablesorter plugin sorts this column with everything else.  I have tried setting the "headers" attribute for the first column, but that only removes sorting capability.  It does not prevent the column from being reordered when I sort by a different column.

Is having a list of row numbers possible with this plugin?  Can you think of a way around the problem?

Comment: To whomever downvoted... if you have a problem with something on StackOverflow, it is better to leave a comment explaining your reasoning.  Otherwise, nobody can learn, and your drive-by downvote isn't worth anything.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It sounds like you need to renumber the rows every time the table is sorted. Try this (use it after you have already initialized tableSorter on your table):

```
var table = $("#myTable");
table.bind("sortEnd",function() { 
    var i = 1;
    table.find("tr:gt(0)").each(function(){
        $(this).find("td:eq(0)").text(i);
        i++;
    });
});
```

Comment: This is perfect!  The only downside is that the old numbers appear for a brief instant while the renumbering occurs, but I'm sure there is nothing that can be done about this.  Thanks again!

Comment: thanks for this code, just used to it to solve a headache, works a treat.

Comment: Perfect answer, just dropped that code right in and it worked!

Comment: Works fine, but when you re-order the table, that column remains unordered. Anyway, good work.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution about the ordenation of the ordinals numbers, based on @Chris Laplante code. The solution is run the *sortEnd* trigger just the first time, when the table is created. So i have to edit the source code. Have to take into account when updates the tablesorter software.

In file ***jquery.tablesorter.js*** around line 370, we can found the trigger:

```
// trigger sortend
setTimeout(function () {
    $(table).trigger("sortEnd");
}, 0);
```

Change for:

```
// trigger sortend
if (runonce == undefined){
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(table).trigger("sortEnd");
    }, 0);
    runonce = true;
}
```

and define the variable *runonce* some place over the function appendToTable:

```
var runonce;                
function appendToTable(table, cache) { ...
```

You can check the result on:[http://formulaeweb.es/resultados.php](http://www.formulaeweb.es/resultados.php) clicking over "Puntos".